# cgi server on android device without root?

Tags: android, python, cgi, httpserver

**I realized a cgi-server on my android device (Acer Iconia Tab A511, Android 4) by a short python script:**

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import os

os.chdir('/sdcard/sl4a')

server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_adress = ('', 8000)

print('CGIHTTPServer an Port 8000 gestartet')

httpd = server(server_adress, handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

**and tried to start a python cgi-script , e.g.:**

```
#! /system/bin/python

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"
print "Hello World!"
```

**Altough this works on a windows machine (by minor changes) without any problems I didn't find a way to make it work on my android device. Do I need *root* to make it work, e.g. I can't chmod my cgi script to executable, or what else should I think of?**

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried and what problems you've had?

Comment: First of all I checked where to find python, as there where a lot of suggestions about the place to find python - /system/bin/python should be the right place. Then I found a page suggesting to chmod 0777 for the cgi-script. This didn't work, maybe because I don't have root on my device. After that I tried to contact Paul Ferrill who wrote that book about Python Programming for Android. He answered that he never tried the cgi-way. So at the moment I'm back to start.